# mySQL indexes, when is too many rows too much?

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on a new system looking at data stored by a CMS about user access logs.

The current table I am looking at extracting data from is currently 5 million rows. This is data spanning about about 11 months. The SQL queries I am making are usually searching on something like `uid` which is an indexed column.

The question I have out of interest and scalablity is how large does a table need to get when even indexed columns don't speed up searches?

Comment: pretty large, wikipedia has all their data stored in a single indexed table. I dont think you have more data than wikipedia, so no worries.

Comment: really?? do you have a source on this? be an interesting read

Comment: Hmm I can search for it. I read it a few years ago so I don't remember the exact source. If I find it ill post it here.

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Mediawiki-database-schema.png? found this from reddit was this want you were referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes will always be faster if the table is mostly read. If you expect writes to scale faster than reads, then updating the index may become more expensive than it's worth.

If `uid` is your primary key, then it will always be indexed and there's really no overhead for this index since MySQL needs a key for each row anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Proper indexes will always speed up queries...that's the point of them.  It doesn't matter how large your table is, the point of the index is to provide the DBMS with an avenue of retrieving a subset of a table faster than if it had to read through the entire table row by row.